# Carousel in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i made a carousel, but i'm having a hard time with the animation. I want it to slide from the right if i click the right button, and from the left if i click the left button. So what i did was create a state `const [classactive, setClassactive] = useState(false);` and said that the img class is `className={classactive == true ? "active-right" : "active-right-2"}`. I did that in order to keep the animation happening. The classes are exactly the same on CSS. So, with the left button, i thought of doing the same but instead of using a class, using a ID, and it did work, the problem is that the right slide animation stoped. I feel like i'm making it more complicated than it really is. The img is an array with each picture's src.

```
<div className="thumb">
          <img
            src={img[index]}
            width="700px"
            className={classactive == true ? "active-right" : "active-right-2"}
            id={idactive == true ? "active-left" : "active-left-2"}
            name="thumbs"
          ></img>
          <div className="label">
            <h1>{projectTitle[index]}</h1>
            <p>{projectDesc[index]}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that ID selectors have a higher specificity than classes, so once your img element has an active ID, the css rules related to that ID will over-rule the classes css.

One approach would be to change the `classactive` state value to be a string representing a variable classname instead of a boolean value, and have the click handler determine that name. This way you don't need any ID's just a single stateful classname.

Following this line of thinking can get quite messy but it's not the most complicated solution. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const carousels = [
    "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg",
    "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg",
    "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"
  ];

  const onNext = () => {
    console.log(carousels.length);

    if (index < carousels.length - 1) {
      let i = index + 1;
      setIndex(i);
    } else {
      setIndex(0);
    }
  };

  const onPrev = () => {
    if (index > 0 && index < carousels.length) {
      let i = index - 1;
      setIndex(i);
    } else {
      setIndex(carousels.length - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      {carousels.map((item, i) =>
        i === index ? (
          <div className="carousel-item" key={i}>
            <img src={item} alt={item} />
          </div>
        ) : null
      )}

      <a className="prev" onClick={onPrev}>
        Prev
      </a>
      <a className="next" onClick={onNext}>
        Next
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 15rem;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```